# Ratio in a random subset without replacement

Tags: probability, approximation

This function returns a random proportion. It appears normally distributed with mean $a/(a+b)$. What is its approximate variance?

```
def sample(a,b,m, alpha):
    pop = ['pos'] * p + ['neg'] * n + ['other'] * (m-a-b)

    sample = np.random.choice(pop, size=int(alpha * len(pop)), replace=False)
    c = Counter(sample)
    pos = c['pos']
    neg = c['neg']
    if pos == neg == 0: return 0.0
    return pos / float(pos + neg)
```

Background:

I have $A$ positive instances and $B$ negative instances in a larger population of size $M > A + B$.
I pick a random sample of size $\alpha  M$ without replacement.
Within my sample, I compute $P$, the ratio of positive / (positive + negative) instances
(ignoring instances which are not positive or negative).
In the very rare case this ratio is undefined, we set it to 0.

Is there a good approximation for $Var[P]$ for large $A,B,M$?

I tried approximating $Var[P] \approx Var[N_{pos} / E[N_{pos\ or\ neg}]]$, where
$N_{pos} \sim Hypergeom(\alpha M, M, A)$ is the number of positive instances chosen,
and $E[N_{pos\ or\ neg}] = \alpha (A + B)$ is the expected number of positive and negative instances in my sample.
But this is not a good estimate in practice.

I can compute the exact probability with the joint distribution of hypergeometric variables $N_{pos} \times N_{pos\ or\ neg}$, but this is too slow to compute for large values of $A,B,M$.

(Motivation: I have a dataset which is split into train and test sets. 
I'm trying to estimate the probability that a certain type of classifier 
will consider a feature as a positive signal on the train set, and a negative signal on the test set.)

Comment: This is a little abstract and hard to follow. It might help if you made it more concrete. How could a classifier "consider a feature as... a negative signal on the test set"?

Comment: I feel like you're asking the wrong question. Everything above the parenthetical remark is with regards to the true value of your parameters. Whereas the parenthetical remark is with respect to your actual classifier. What you should instead be looking at is the ROC curves for your training and test sets, and their respective confidence intervals, as found here: http://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Confidence_Intervals_for_the_Area_Under_an_ROC_Curve.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback guys -- it turns out I'd made a typo in my code! The estimate $$Var[sample(A,B,M,\alpha)] \approx \frac{Var[Hypergeom(\alpha M, M, A)]}{(\alpha(A+B))^2}$$ was good enough for my purposes!